# apt package for 11.04 for Python 2.7.3?

Tags: 11.04, apt, python, python-2.7

I want to upgrade Python on my 11.04 server from Python 2.7.1 to Python 2.7.3.  I assumed that if I did an `apt-get install Python2.7` that 2.7.3 would have automatically been available and would have updated.  But instead I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python2.7 
python2.7 is already the newest version.
```

Is there a different repository I need to get it from?  Or is it not ported to 11.04?  I want some education on which packages and versions are available for previous Ubuntu versions.

Comment: See if this applies to you https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bug/990974

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the latest version of the `python2.7` package [available in the Natty repositories is 2.7.1-5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/python2.7).

2.7.3 is only [officially available for Precise 12.04.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python2.7)  You would have to compile this yourself for 11.04, or search for a PPA containing it.

To find out the latest version of a package available for a specific release, simply go to:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/release-name/package-name
```

where the *release-name* is *natty, oneiric,* etc.

To find out all available versions of a specific package and the releases they correspond to, look at:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=package-name
```

or at:

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/package-name
```